# C++ Printing value of pointer gives strange result

Tags: c++, pointers

When I compile and run this C++ code, I am not getting the output I expected.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int * i = new int;
    long * l = new long;
    char * c = new char[100];
    float * f = new float[100];

    cout << "i " << i << endl;
    cout << "l " << l << endl;
    cout << "c " << c << endl;
    cout << "f " << f << endl;


    delete i;
    delete l;
    delete []c;
    delete []f;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

On a unix machine I get

```
i 0x967f008
l 0x967f018
c
f 0x967f090
```

On a windows machine the value for c prints as over a line of random characters.

Please can someone explain why it's not printing the pointer for the char array correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`operator <<` for `std::ostream` and `std::wostream` is defined in  special way for char pointers(`char*`, `const char*`, `wchar_t*` and `const wchar_t*` to print out a null-terminated string. This enables you to write

```
const char* str = "Hello, World";
std::cout << str;
```

and see a nice string on your stdout.

To get the pointer value, cast to `void *`

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(c)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `operator<<` is overloaded for `char*`. It will consider that you are trying to print a C-style string, and print all the chars until it finds a `0x00`. Since you're not initializing the allocated memory, it will print out random garbage.

Comment: what is the C++ way of doing: `(void *)c`?

Comment: that would be `reinterpret_cast<void*>(c)`.

Comment: @hexa: Although @Mat is right in that `(void*)c` is equivalent of `reinterpret_cast<void*>(c)`, the *C++ way* of doing it is `static_cast<void*>(c)`;

Answer (score 1):

The char * is actually a C string. So I'm guessing it is trying to print it as a string.

One way to force the pointer address to be printed is to use printf:

```
printf("%p\n", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no initialization in the char's pointed by c, you dump some random memory values till it found one with value 0. It will sometimes crash, when zero is not find until your readable memory finish. Writing code like this is forbidden and *wrong* in Unix too, and in any other operating system.